# Angularjs How to define invite id's by variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-hangouts

I am trying to add google hangouts button to make calls by emails. If I hardcoded the email button works fine but Can I use a string variable for invite id so I can dynamically render hongout buttons? Example: invites[{ id : person.email }].

```
           <g:hangout render="createhangout"
                       invites="[{ id : 'foo@gmail.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
            </g:hangout>
```

Here is the repeater code block. What am I missing?

```
 <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="person in contacts | orderBy:'name'">
                {{person.name}}  {{person.surname | uppercase}} --> {{person.email}} - <button ng-click="del($index)">Delete</button>
                <g:hangout render="createhangout"
                           invites="[{ id : '{{person.email}}', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
                </g:hangout>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

But also I am trying to update and add new persons so to create hangout buttons dynamically. I think my main problem is that.Here is the all code.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html data-ng-app="hangoutApp">
   <body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <h2>Add a person to contact:</h2>
        <br />
        Enter Name:
        <input type="text" data--ng-model="name" /> 
        <br />
        <br />
        Enter Surname:
        <input type="text" data--ng-model="surname" />
        <br />
        <br />
        Enter Email:
        <input type="text" data--ng-model="email" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button ng-click="addPerson()">Add New Person</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="person in contacts | orderBy:'name'">
                {{person.name}}  {{person.surname | uppercase}} --> {{person.email}} - <button ng-click="del($index)">Delete</button>
                <g:hangout render="createhangout"
                           invites="[{ id : '{{person.email}}', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
                </g:hangout>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var hangoutApp = angular.module('hangoutApp', []);

        var controllers = {};
        controllers.SimpleController = function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.name = "";
            $scope.surname = "";
            $scope.email = "";
            $scope.contacts = [];
            $scope.addPerson = function () {
                this.contacts.push({
                    name: this.name,
                    surname: this.surname,
                    email: this.email
                });
            }
            $scope.del = function (ind) {
                this.contacts = this.contacts.splice(ind, 1);
            };

        }


        hangoutApp.controller(controllers);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the code? The original from Google? Can you post the original one?

Comment: Try it and find out.  If it fails, edit your question with the details and we'll try to help.

Comment: I forgot to add but I already tried and failed I cannot use varible in this structure.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using {{}} in the snippet i've also added a repeater so you can make a bunch of these on the fly.

```
<g:hangout  render="createhangout"
                       invites="[{ id : '{{person.Email}}', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
</g:hangout>
```

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){ 
  $scope.people = [{Email:'aEmail@gmail.com'}];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="person in people">
<g:hangout  render="createhangout"
                       invites="[{ id : '{{person.Email}}', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
    </g:hangout>
  <span>{{person.Email}}</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still something is missing I could not render it. I will update the code with my repeater part. Can u check it again?

Comment: There could be an issue with dynamic loading of the hangout buttons, what happens if you do a repeater with a hard coded email?

Comment: When it is hardcoded there is no problem. It is rendered well. But I want to add new persons and update the list accordingly. That is why I am using angular but I am new at angular so Is there any way to render buttons dynamically?

Comment: So because you're using a custom tag (g:hangout) there is going to be a lifecycle that causes the buttons to render.  As a result it may not be possible to use angular in this situation. It may be that you have to coordinate the loading of the google script to render the buttons.